# how to create basic stick figure type animation movies?

Tags: animation

I want to make a simple animation movie with stick figures like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kr_DGf77OhM

I am an indie coder so I am completely new to this. My goal is to be able to make simple marketing videos for my apps.

I want to know where to start - what tools should i be looking at? I do not want anything fancy - I just want to move around some stick figures and some images I have, and I can add voice to the movie.
I'm sure it is not as simple as I am thinking - but would appreciate some recommendations on where to start.

Comment: there is nothing simple about it. Many complex looking 3D anims are in fact just as hard.

Comment: I can imagine. I wanted to know what tools/software to start with. The question may be research oriented, hence unsuitable for this forum.

Comment: Most probably it was done in flash. Second most probably after effects. but its hard to say nearly any program could have been used. I would have used Maya.